# Symfony2 multiple routes on controller

Tags: php, symfony

using symfony2 with annotations on controller in order to route.

To not repeat myself I'm trying to define 2 routes on controller's class declartion as following

```
/** 
 * @Route(
 *      "/{_locale}/productmanufacturer",
 *      name="tes2"
 *      )
 * @Route(
 *      "/productmanufacturer",
 *      name="tes1",
 *      defaults={"_locale", "pt_BR"}
 *      )
 */
 class ProductManufacturerController extends Controller
 {
  ...
 }
```

And the 2nd route doesn't appear. If I put same annotion over an Action, the route work. Does anyone know how to put 2 routes as quoted above?

Answer (score 0):

For translating routes look at this: http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle

With this bundle you can also get rid of the locale in your url simply by starting your route with an underscore: http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle/master/usage#leaving-routes-untranslated

Comment: I'll check it out later. But do you recomend fullfilling an application with bundles, even when I'm just trying to learn and make something simple?

Comment: Yes. Symfony is all about bundles. And there are so many bundles that can make your life so much easier. I think it's a good thing to start right away with the right strategy.